# Advantages of using a standard JSON-RPC implementation

Tags: json, standards, json-rpc

I always end up using my own minimalistic wrapper for JSON-RPC (because it's trivially simple): am I missing out on something compared to standard libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's simple. In past I took similar approach as yours and had my own minimal json-rpc implementation. Now I use [jsonrpc2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonrpc2/#json-rpc2-example) for a fairly complex application. What I was missing earlier

- Didn't have batched call support
- All error code supported
- better tested library
- more goodies like rpc processor (check jsonrpc2's documentation)
- other obvious advantages of open source :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a .net jsonrpc2 server. Check out http://jsonrpc2.codeplex.com/

I would also add to Shekhar's list

- Speed of development by skipping the 'roll your own' step.
- Cost - is most cost effective to use a library supported by the community.
- Its likely better tested, and more stable then a roll your own solution.
- Performance of the json-rpc server is likely better then you would get with a roll your own solution.
- ** maintainability ** There is documentation around Json-Rpc 2. Another developer will be able to contribute on your project or fix bugs better if the protocol has a defined spec. They may be familiar with it already.
- In the case of Json-Rpc.net, to make a method a json-rpc method, all you have to do is add an attribute to the method. So another plus for using a real json-rpc implementation.